# Can Allomancers Soothe or Riot themselves?

Tags: magical-theory, cosmere, mistborn

In *Mistborn*, can Allomancers burn zinc and brass to Riot or Soothe their own emotions, such as to calm down if scared or cause a fight-or-flight reaction to trigger adrenaline?

Comment: Unfortunately for them **no**, it's external power.

Comment: probably not because they put out soothing in waves and it doesnt affect them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are explicitly stated not to be able to:

> He knew himself a fool. However, he could not help how he felt. One could not use emotional Allomancy on one’s self 
> <sub>*The Well of Ascension* chapter 46, page 578 (2014 trade paperback edition)</sub>